# Setting values of nested struct fields using reflection in Go

Tags: go, reflection, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create a protobuf structure out of a

```
type FlatMessage map[string][]byte
```

and I'm struggling with setting values of nested fields.

I have an

```
func (fm *FlatMessage) Unflatten() (pb.Message, error)
```

method to transform flat message into structured protobuf.

I also have a helper function called `analyze` which takes a struct of type `pb.Message` and returns a `map[int]*ProtoField` where:

```
type ProtoField struct {
    Name  string
    Type  reflect.Type
}
```

i.e. `analyze` traverses `pb.Message` recursively and gathers all the information I need about it. So far so good.

Now when I go key by key through my `FlatMessage`, the key is an encoded field number of a respective protobuf field, and I can set it using reflection, like this:

```
r := reflect.ValueOf(&result).Elem().FieldByName(field.Name)
if r.IsValid() {
    r.Set(scalarValue)
}
```

but that works only when the `field.Name` in question does not refer to a nested field, i.e., setting `OldV1Id` works fine, but attempting to set `Profile.Id` or, say, `Destination.Address.TypeOfNumber`, results in:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value [recovered]
    panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that my `r` becomes `<invalid Value>` when called on a field which is a nested one, but how can I work around it?

My `r` is of course not `valid`, not addressable, and not settable. I can make a `reflect.New` out of it, but I can't figure out how to set that new `reflect.Value` in such a way that the field of my original structures becomes modified. No matter what I do the my function doesn't modify fields with nested names with this approach.

Another solution I tried is adding a
        Value reflect.Value
to my `ProtoField` structure, and modifying `analyze` so that it appends a `reflect.ValueOf(s).Field(i)` where `s` is the top-level struct `interface{}` and `i` is its ith field. Then whenever I encounter a field that is a nested one, I call `r := reflect.ValueOf(field.Value)`, but then the problem is I'm unable to call `r.Set(scalarValue)` because of incompatible types.

Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Build slice of field indexes as you walk the structure in analyze. Store the indexes in ProtoField. Use godoc.org/reflect#Value.FieldByIndex to get field.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. [ThunderCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369213/setting-values-of-nested-struct-fields-using-reflection-in-go#comment91688864_52369213) was right in his comment: the trick is to use `FieldByIndex`. I didn't notice the signature of that method before, I thought it accepts an integer as an argument, but in fact it takes a *slice* of integers. It was then easy to modify my `analyze` function that traverses the structure recursively and now also constructs a slice of indexes as it goes. Now I can just `r := reflect.ValueOf(&result).Elem().FieldByIndex(field.Idx)` and I'm laughing.

Lesson learned here: if you want to set values of nested `struct` fields using reflection, don't call them by name; call them by index.